# Almacenar valores en Array desde fetch

Tags: javascript, json, array, api, fetch

```
let arrayDatos = [];

arrayDatos = fetch('url')
 .then(response => response.json())
 .then(posts => return posts)
```

Estoy tratando de llenar un array con datos que me retorna la funcion **fetch**, pero por asincronidad de **Javascript** no logro que se llene. Utilice promesas y tampoco logro dar con el código.

Es posible hacer esto?

Comment: Bienvenido para entender mejor el funcionamiento del sitio te invitio a dar un [tour]

Comment: Jonathan, si puedieras mostrar un ejemplo reproduciendo el error, podriamos ayudarte.

Comment: podrías indicar cuál es el resultado esperado y que resultado obtienes de manera más puntual?

Answer (score 1):

bajo mi  punto de vista podrias recorrer uno a uno los registros o datos que retorna tu fetch, luego esto ir agregando en un array algo asi:

```
var data = new Array();
for (i=0; i<dataRetornante.length; i++){
var element={}
element.id=dataRetornante[i]['id'];
element.nombre= dataRetornante[i]['nombre];
data.append(element);
}
console.log(data);//aqui estaria tu resultado en el array data
//dataRetornante es el resultado de tu funcion fetch
```

suerte ..!!

Answer (score 1):

Lo único que tienes que hacer es:

```
const arrayDatos = fetch(url).then(res => res.json())
```

Lo que vas a almacenar es una promesa conteniendo los datos obtenidos mediante la petición AJAX. Ten presente que `fetch` devuelve una promesa con el resultado de la petición; por consiguiente, para acceder a los datos deberás hacer uso de `then`:

```
arrayDatos.then((datos) => {
  // hacer algo con los datos
})
```

Sin embargo, si lo que quieres es almacenar los datos directamente desde la petición; puedes hacer uso de Funciones Asíncronas para esperar al resultado de la promesa:

> **Nota**: Para hacer uso de esta característica el código en donde se llame a `await` debe estar en una función marcada con `async`.

```
const obtenerDatos = async () => {
  const arrayDatos = await fetch(url).then(res => res.json())
  arrayDatos[0] // un valor
  // resto de código
}
```

Cabe aclarar que **toda función marcada con `async` devuelve una promesa** independientemente de si se retorne o no algo explícitamente.

Answer (score 1):

Yo pude hacer eso que decís de la siguiente manera:

```js
export const arrayDatos = []

fetch('url')
.then ((respuesta) => respuesta.json())
.then ((data) => {
    data.forEach((elemento) =>{
        stock.push(elemento)
    })
})
```

Espero te sirva! Saludos